# _filename.java meaning in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a standard in java to use _ [underscore] in front of variable or class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899683/is-there-a-standard-in-java-to-use-underscore-in-front-of-variable-or-class)

Can anyone tell whether an underscore before the java filename has a special meaning or its just a normal java file? (means can we have a java file named _abc.java as a normal java file or it has some special functions in it)

Thanks

Comment: (Ask the person who named it that way - does the class it contains *also* have an underscore? Is said class *used* at all? That would be the bigger/core mystery ..)

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to other Java files but these naming conventions are followed to distinguish a file from other files.

Lets say, in your project you want to define some special constants OR want to have some special functions, then you should name the file in such a way so it can be easily distinguished. `_` fits for it.

Comment: And what is that Distinguishing Quality of that file?

Comment: @AmitD: Edited. does it answer your question?

Comment: @AmitD The 'distinguishing quality' is that its name starts with '_'. What that means in your specific case is a specific question that only the person who did it can answer. Anything you get here will be just guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special. But it means simply that code is not adhering to [standard java convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) given by Sun