# What is the meaning of the leading underline of "val = _val"? Does it have some deep use or deep meaning? In Java

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

In one algorithm question "Implement Queue by Linked List", the solution shows create the class Node first:

```
class Node {
    public int val;
    public Node next;
    public Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

May I ask the meaning of the leading underline of `val = _val`?

Comment: `=` is the [assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), and `val` and `_val` are [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).  If you aren't familiar with these concepts, I'd highly suggest working through all the languages basics tutorials.

Comment: See where it says `public Node(int _val) {`? `_val` means the same thing in `val = _val` that it does in `public Node(int _val) {`: it's a **name** for the value that was passed in. To be quite frank, if this confuses you, then you are many lessons away from understanding the assignment.

Comment: See also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899683.  (NOT a duplicate)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you might be right, but you completely forgot to mention why naming conventions and explicit naming is so important in programming. You know that sometimes even for experienced developers such as you and me, terrible naming can be confusing. Based on my experience, I am pretty sure the source of confusion is the leading underscore in the variable name. I am certain the OP thinks that it carries some deeper meaning (which we know it doesn't).

Comment: There are languages where that sort of thing could have special meaning, and there are best practice guidelines for those languages that (mandate, forbid, encourage, etc. depending) those kinds of thing. All of that *should still be discussed in a tutorial for the language*, if it's any good.

Comment: @hfontanez Thank you. Yes, that's what confused me. I thought the leading underscore is for special use or deeper meaning that I should learn. Now I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_val` is just a name.  This code is exactly equivalent in every way to

```
public Node(int iJustMadeUpAVariableName) {
  val = iJustMadeUpAVariableName;
  next = null;
}
```

and it initializes the `val` field in the `Node` class to the value passed into the constructor.

Comment: @Linda Lu, I would like to add to Louis' answer that the leading underscore DOES NOT carry any hidden meaning. It is just a character. The Java language places restrictions on the characters that can be used to start a variable name, but the underscore is obviously not one of those characters. I suggest you do some research into Java naming rules and conventions.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the underscore before have a deep meaning or use that I never learned. Then now I know.